# Messy dictionary output in python

Tags: python, dictionary, output, reverse

I'm trying to output some variables from a dictionary, but it doesn't output it in the order that I assigned.
I know that dictionary has no order, but I need a dictionary for another purpose so I can't use a list. I was wondering whether there is a way to make the output be at the same order that I assigned the values in the first place.

Input:

```
a = {'Name': "a", 'Date': 20021501, 'Time': 1800, 'Type': "JK", 'TG': 68, 'DC': 98}
```

Output:

```
{'TG': 68, 'DC': 98, 'Time': 1800, 'Date': 20021501, 'Type': 'JK', 'Name': 'a'}
```

Thanks to any helper

Comment: Look at Python's OrderedDict http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-372-adding-an-ordered-dictionary-to-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

If you don't need to modify the data, you could also consider a `namedtuple`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 0):

OrderedDict keeps things in the order that you assigned them. I don't often find that useful, but if that is what you need use it.

Alternatively, if you are not really using the "dictionary" access property, consider just storing a list of tuples, 2-tuples here, if you do not need to modify either member of the tuple.

```
a = [('Name', 'Joe'), ('Age, '10')]
for element in a:
   print 'key {0}, value {1}'.format (element [0], element [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OrderedDict:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they
>   remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an
>   ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys
>   were first added.

This subclass of OrderedDict will remember the order that entries were LAST inserted:

```
class LastUpdatedOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    'Store items in the order the keys were last added'

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            del self[key]
        OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

That link also shows that you can take a normal dictionary, sort it, and store it in order as an OrderedDict.